# How much bourbon is the right amount?

Tags: bourbon, whiskey, additives

When adding something like bourbon (or other whiskeys) to the secondary, how much do you add? I realize this will differ based on recipes, tastes, and styles, but what is a good range? How much is so minimal that you won't taste it, and how much is so much that it will overpower the grains and significantly increase the ABV of the final product?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no right or wrong answer for this. You start small and add to taste. Of course your taste will differ from anyone else but there is no formula or standard amount. Just remember to document the amounts you add, so the next time you will have a reference.

Answer (score 3):

I would say don't add it to secondary at all.
Add it a little at a time at bottling, mixing and adding to taste.

Track the amount you use and if you make the beer in the future, you can just add that entire amount again.

That said, I have had good luck pitching a 12oz-16oz of bourbon into 5 gallons and getting decent flavor.  Depends really on the flavor profile of the base beer.

Comment: I used 16 ounces in the bacon bourbon yesterday. mm mm mm